# Vertex paint and bake color id?

Tags: texturing

Hi i always bake color id with use material and color diffuse, but now i do my model option brush in blender. I use vertex paint for this : 
[image]

It is possible to bake color id with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Input** > **Attribute** node to feed **Vertex Colors** to **Diffuse** node and than **Bake Diffuse Color** as usual.

[image: final]